# Get residue position from Pymol Selection

Tags: pymol

I can make a selection in Pymol using the resi parameter. Is there a way to get this resi data back out of a selection object? The only thing I found so far is how to get the position, as in the x/y/z coordinates from a selection.

For context, I have a table with a set of data points for each residue in the amino acid sequence of the displayed structure and I want to write a function where I can print the data based on the current selection. So my thought would be something like the following, where the content of the *'get_residue_positions_for_selection'* function would be what I'm asking about.

```
def show_selection_position_data():
    residue_data = {
        "header": ['variation', 'rmsf']
        , "1": ['high', 0.1]
        , ...
    }
    selections = cmd.get_names('selection')

    if sele not in selections:
        print("No selection")
        return

    residues = get_residue_positions_for_selection("sele")

    for residue in residue_selections:
        print(residue_data[residue])

    return
```

Comment: This certainly a very interesting question and a cool answer. The advice I was given (to pretty much the same problem) was to use Pymol scripting directly rather than via Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some more searching I found the answer.

You have to use the **cmd.iterate** function to iterate over the default selection ("sele", first parameter). With the second parameter you can push the variables you need into an array for later access. In this case I wanted the residue number so I used the variable 'resv'. A full list of the variables exposed by the iterate function can be found on the [pymolwiki](https://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Iterate)

Note that you can use a function call as the second parameter and if you need a more complex selection than 'sele' you can use selector.process in the iterate function.

Here is my final working function. Note that I used a set for storing the residue ids, since the iterate function technically iterates over the atoms and so the same residue will likely appear multiple times in your selection.

```
def show_selection_position_data():
    residue_data = {
            "header": ['variation', 'rmsf']
            , 1: ['high', 0.1]
            , 2: ['high', 0.2]
            , 3: ['low', 0.1]
            , 4: ['high', 0.05]
            , 5: ['middle', 0.2]
            , 6: ['high', 0.1]
            , 7: ['high', 0.1]
        }
    selections = cmd.get_names('selections')

    if "sele" not in selections:
        print("No selection")
        return

    userSelection = "sele"

    stored.residues = set()
    cmd.iterate(selector.process(userSelection), 'stored.residues.add(resv)')

    for residue in stored.residues:
        if residue in residue_data:
            print(residue_data[residue])
        else:
            print("{}: no data".format(residue))

    return
```

Comment: Nice. And thank you for taking the time to post an answer!